# Vim outputs a complete list of all registered autocommands on startup

Tags: vim

After I made a change to my vimrc, vim started outputting a list of all autocommands currently registred.  It looks like this:

```
*:echo "Hello " . $USER . ", how may I help you?"
VimResized
*exe "normal! \<c-w>="
cline  WinEnter
*set cursorline
nuline  WinEnter
*if !exists("b:NERDTreeType") | setlocal number | endif
cline  WinLeave
*set nocursorline
nuline  WinLeave
*if !exists("b:NERDTreeType") | setlocal nonumber | endif
CursorMoved
*call FixScroll(5)
CursorMovedI
*call FixScroll(5)
```

The above example are the last several lines of output before vim starts up.
I scoured my vimrc for a statement which lists autocommands, *(such as an `autocmd` with no arguments)* but to no avail.  Is it possible to trace back to what is displaying the registered autocommands?

Here is my vimrc just in case I missed something:
https://github.com/4Evergreen4/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an "incomplete" `:autocmd` will query the autocmd's. e.g. `:autocmd` will query all autocmd's and `:autocmd CursorHold` will query all autocmd that use `CursorHold`.

You can fix this is either find the malformed `:autocmd` by sight or you can use the tried and true method of disabling/commenting out half your `~/.vimrc` to see if the error is in that half. Continue this binary search until you find the offending line.